# Как читать сообщения на сервере через tcp?

Tags: tcp, rust

Почему-то код ниже отказывается печатать пришедшее сообщение от клиента.
Tcp клиент работает нормально, тестировал на другом языке этот серверный код.
Также код на rust ниже может напечатать, если указать вручную `println!("new client");`, то он выведет, а вот сообщения от пользователя почему-то нет. Что делать?

```
use std::net::{TcpListener};
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    start_server();
}

fn start_server() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        thread::spawn(|| {
            let stream = stream.unwrap();
            let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
            let mut response = String::new();
            reader.read_line(&mut response).expect("could not read");
            println!("Server received {}", response);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно, клиенты не присылают перевод строки. Хорошо бы и код клиентов минимальный приводить.

Comment: Соглашусь с @KoVadim. Потыкал telnet'ом, всё работает.

Comment: Потыкал телнетом тоже, работает

Comment: @KoVadim, а можно команду telnet глянуть:)

Answer (score 0):

Банально при отправке сообщения с клиента, просто забыл \n